# How to retrieve value of 'Expires' property of ASP cookie?

Tags: cookies, vbscript, asp-classic

I have created a cookie in ASP called `language` which was set to the string `"VBScript"`. I've attached an `Expires` property to that with the value of `#May 1,2016#`. I was able to retrieve the cookie's value, but I am having  a problem retrieving the expiration date. Here is the ASP code:

```
<%
    response.write("Cookie: " & Request.Cookies("language")) ' outputs 'VBScript' 
    response.write("Expiration Date: " & Request.Cookies("language").Expires) ' possible line of error
%>
```

When I run this code, next to the value of the cookie, it says 'An error occurred while processing the URL. Please contact the system administrator. If you are the system administrator click here to find out more about this error.' The 'here' part was a link to the Microsoft website. I may consider removing the 'possible line of error', but is there a way to retrieve the expiration date of the cookie in this situation?

### Update:

Removing the 'possible line of error' just removed the error message and just displayed the cookie's value.

Comment: What you need it for, exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From: [Response.Cookies Collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524757(v=vs.90).aspx)

> Expires
>   Write-only. The date on which the Cookie expires. This date
>   must be set in order for the Cookie to be stored on the client's disk
>   after the session ends. If this attribute is not set to a date beyond
>   the current date, the Cookie expires when the session ends.

It is a write-only value, cannot read from it.

And the [Request.Cookies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525394(v=vs.90).aspx) collection has no key called `Expires`.

Comment: Sadly and oddly enough, that is true. Once you set expiration date for a cookie, it's not possible to read that value again with code - neither server side, nor client side.

Comment: Oh, I see now. Thanks.

Comment: and I wonder why Write-only ? what nonsense is this ? like a magic black box - you put something in, and pufffff, it disappears.